# Dockerfile RUN lpadmin to add a printer not working in the built image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to add a printer in Dockerfile RUN command, so this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM dassh/eline:base
MAINTAINER dassh
# start cups service is necessary to run lpadmin command
RUN service cups start && lpadmin -p VLM2601 -v EleanBackend:/tmp -m 
VLM2601_gdi.ppd -E && echo done
```

**Build procedure**

```
docker build -t dassh/eline .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  722.9kB
Step 1/3 : FROM dassh/eline:base
 ---> 712dce8cd557
Step 2/3 : MAINTAINER dassh
 ---> Running in 2f3f5f80b665
Removing intermediate container 2f3f5f80b665
 ---> 2b53b81d6ff4
Step 3/3 : RUN service cups start && lpadmin -p VLM2601 -v EleanBackend:/tmp -m VLM2601_gdi.ppd -E && echo done
 ---> Running in f176fbdf765e
 * Starting Common Unix Printing System cupsd
   ...done.
done
Removing intermediate container f176fbdf765e
 ---> e229e278b085
Successfully built e229e278b085
Successfully tagged dassh/eline:latest
```

The build was successful without any error. But when I started a container with this image, I found that the printer wasn't added.

```
dassh@ubuntu:~$ docker run -itd dassh/eline /bin/bash
a8785057e71a598cd391f355848819295fef8e311090f70cbae95ca5360856c2
dassh@ubuntu:~$ docker cp ~/123.pdf a8:/
dassh@ubuntu:~$ docker attach a8
root@a8785057e71a:/pdf_to_prn# 
root@a8785057e71a:/pdf_to_prn# service cups start            
 * Starting Common Unix Printing System cupsd                                                                                                       [ OK ] 
root@a8785057e71a:/pdf_to_prn# lp -o fit-to-page -o media=A4 -d VLM2601 /123.pdf
lp: The printer or class does not exist.
```

The command returns an error that the printer does not exist, but when I execute add printer command in the container manually, and run lp command again, everything is fine.

```
root@a8785057e71a:/pdf_to_prn# lpadmin -p VLM2601 -v EleanBackend:/tmp -m VLM2601_gdi.ppd -E
root@a8785057e71a:/pdf_to_prn# lp -o fit-to-page -o media=A4 -d VLM2601 /123.pdf
request id is VLM2601-1 (1 file(s))
```

Therefore, my adding printer command has no issues. So what is happening?

Comment: Please add you base docker file also? Do you know where `lpadmin` persists this info?

Comment: @TarunLalwani the base docker file is only install cups service and printer driver, there should not have any influence. Secondary, I‘m not really sure what you mean. lpadmin command not return any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem cause by use `lpadmin` create printer.

1. system get printers by file `/etc/cups/printers.conf`.
2. use `lpadmin` add a printer will generate or update file `/etc/cups/printers.conf`.
3. **step 2 is asynchronous!** (It takes almost 30s in my test after execute lpadmin command)

Dockerfile RUN this step complete before file `/etc/cups/printers.conf` generated.